# how to work with air adobe

Tags: air

I have aptana studio and install the air adobe 2.0 beta version. I have export a sample program with the extension of air.. But i dont know how to instal it to show as a windows application..

My requirement is :: I want to show up a html page as a windows application. Am i going in the right path. Please help me how to proceed it.

And also i am having some sample air file downloaded from websites.. How to work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. intall AIR runtime
2. then clicking the "*.air" file will install it (system will invoke AIR runtime)
3. the AIR runtime will also create short-cuts for you, which will be shown as windows application

Comment: yes for that we need to install the ADOBE AIR INSTALLER. Its nearly 15 mb.. Any how thanks..

Answer (score 0):

As Francis mentions and the [devnet](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/ajax/getting_started.html) guide as well, make sure you have AIR installed.

I haven't used Aptana for AIR, but their [run guide](http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Running_an_AIR_application) looks pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Adobe Air SDK and Update the path accordingly.
2. Install Adobe Air.
3. Build the application and package it.
4. Run the *.air file by double clicking on it.
5. Follow this tutorial to run a Hello World.http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-adobe-air--net-986